# ifort with geany problem

Tags: intel, geany

I've changed my build/compile commands on geany to use Intel's Fortran:

```
    ifort -c "%f"
    ifort "%f" -o "%e"
```

When I try compiling, I get the following error:

```
ifort "file.f90" -o "file" (in directory: ...)
Compilation failed.
/bin/sh: 1: ifort: not found
```

However, I can type

```
    ifort -o file file.f90
```

in terminal and it will compile with no problem. I can open geany from terminal with the command "LANG=C geany --verbose" which fixes geany's inability to find ifort, but have not found a way to get the unity launcher to use that.

So: does anyone know how to get unity launcher to use the command **or** fix geany to accept ifort *without* above command?

Comment: Are all Intel related variables written in `~/.profile` file?

Comment: Yes. I have put the `source /opt/intel/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64` command in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files. Still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ifort as a symbolic link in the /usr/bin folder. That solves the whole problem.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/bin/intel64/ifort /usr/bin/ifort
```

Replace the path with whatever version of Intel Composer you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Run Geany from terminal using `LANG=C geany --verbose`. Set the build commands to Intel Fortran as specified above. It compiles and runs without any problem.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, then I stated that this is the solution that I *didn't* want to use. Jadelord's solution of getting it into PATH is the correct choice.